# MIPS Reversing strings separated by newline characters

Tags: string, assembly, stack, mips, push

I am trying to reverse string separated by newlines, without moving the positions of the newlines. I used a stack and my use of the stack is appropriate, however I keep getting a bad address in data/stack read exception.

my int_buffer would be a (really long) string of the form "123\n65\n893\n45\n" and so on
and my output string should be, given the above input: "321\n56\n398\n54\n"

so far when I run the program, I get an exception after the first string before the newline is processed

```
la $a0, int_buffer
la $a1, str_buffer

push:
    lbu $t0, 0($a0)             # load address of character

    beqz $t0, buffer_end            # branch to end if end of buffer

    beq $t0, 10, pop            # branch to pop if newline

    subu $sp, $sp, 1
    sb $t0, ($sp)               # store char in stack
    addi $a0, $a0, 1            # increment input pointer

    j push

pop:
    lb $t0, 0($s0)              # load char in stack
    addu $sp, $sp, 1

    beqz $t0, add_newline       # branch to add newline after current set of strings

    sb $t0, 0($a1)
    addi $a1, $a1, 1            # increment output pointer
    j pop

add_newline:
    li $t0, 10
    sb $t0, 0($a1)

    addi $a0, $a0, 1            # skip newline
    addi $a1, $a1, 1            # move to next index

    j push                      # push the next set of string


buffer_end:

    # print out contents in str_buffer

    # exit
```

Comment: You have a typo `lb $t0, 0($s0)` should be `$sp`. Anyway, use your debugger to find the cause of crashes.

Comment: You're not pushing a null, but popping looking for s null.

Comment: You can reverse a string by swapping bytes without making a copy.  Basically don't need the stack or any intermediate copying.

Comment: @ErikEidt thanks, i fixed the null popping thing and it worked